# Get the Type of a Core Data relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is there an easy way to find the object type which forms a specific relationship in Core Data?

For example, I have a one-to-many relationship:

```
Battery-----1-to-Many-----Comment
```

If I didn't know that the relationship was for a specific `Comment` object, is there a programatic way I could find out which object type it is, based solely on the set that I'm dealing with.

Something along the lines of

```
battery.comments.classType = [Comment class]
```

I'm aware that both `Battery` and `Comment` are of type `NSManagedObject` - I'd like to know more specifically what they are.

I'm also aware that if the `NSSet` contains any data, I can use any one of it's objects to query the type.  However I need to cater for when there is no data in the `NSSet`.
Thank you.

Comment: You can do [[NSManagedObject entity] name] which will give you the name of the entity. Then compare that to NSStringFromClass([Comment class]); for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all info you need from this few lines:

```
    NSRelationshipDescription* rel = [[[battery entity] relationshipsByName] valueForKey:@"comments"];
    NSString* className = [[rel destinationEntity] managedObjectClassName];
    NSString* entityName = [[rel destinationEntity] name];
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You're a genius.  The code I used was: Class entityClass = NSClassFromString(childEntityClassName);

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate you have an [NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) typed property. It has an `entities` array containing [NSEntityDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSEntityDescription)s. From here you should be able to figure it out. Hope this helps!